# Java and MySQL query Date

Tags: java, mysql, date

My Java code is this:

```
public void FillCombo_Disp(){
    java.sql.Date fromDate = new java.sql.Date(jDateChooser_Date1.getDate().getTime());
    java.sql.Date toDate= new java.sql.Date(jDateChooser_Date2.getDate().getTime());
    String space = jComboBox_Space.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String [] space_split = space.split(" ");
    String id_space = space_split[0];
    String query = "SELECT ID FROM Rent WHERE ID_Space = '" + id_space + "' AND Date1 BETWEEN ? AND ? OR Dat2 BETWEEN ? AND ?";
    try {
        pst = conn.Connection().prepareStatement(query);
        pst.setDate(1, fromDate);
        pst.setDate(2, toDate);
        pst.setDate(3, fromDate);
        pst.setDate(4, toDate);

        ResultSet res = pst.executeQuery();
        int ID = 0;
        while(res.next()) {
            ID = res.getInt("ID");
        }

        if(ID!=0)
            jTextField_Disp.setText("Rented");
        else
            jTextField_Disp.setText("Free");
    } catch(Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

My function is to control two dates entered by a user and compare them to the database. If the dates are within the range of time you should give me back the id_rent.
But I don't understand why cannot enter in while loop:

```
while(res.next()) {
    ID = res.getInt("ID");
}
```

Help me!

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "why cannot enter in while loop:"?

Comment: Your SQL statement is suspect. In MySQL, the `AND` operator has a higher order of precedence than the `OR` operator. e.g. "**`fee AND fi OR fo`**" is equivalent to "**`(fee AND fi) OR fo`**".  I suspect you want to add some parens: "**`fee AND (fi OR fo)`**'. I'm also curious why the value of **`id_space`** is included as a literal in the SQL text, rather than a bind placeholder (like the date values.) I suggest that you verify that your SQL statement is working correctly (from another client).

Comment: The while loop is used to determine if my question query and I can return the data. I checked with MySQL workbench my query.

Answer (score 2):

You made a spelling mistake in your query so it returns no rows. You put the word "Dat2" when i believe it should be "Date2".

Current:

```
String query = "SELECT ID FROM Rent WHERE ID_Space = '" + id_space + "' AND Date1 BETWEEN ? AND ? OR Dat2 BETWEEN ? AND ?";
```

New:

```
String query = "SELECT ID FROM Rent WHERE ID_Space = '" + id_space + "' AND Date1 BETWEEN ? AND ? OR Date2 BETWEEN ? AND ?";
```

Comment: Thanks Baseball435  :) I corrected the mistake, but it doesn't work the same :(